# 2 way binding in UITableView using RxSwift

Tags: uitableview, rx-swift, 2-way-object-databinding, rx-cocoa, rxdatasources

I am using MVVM pattern with [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift), [RxCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/master/RxCocoa), [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources).

[image]

I have successfully populated the `UITableView` with array of `PaletteViewModel` present in `ListViewModel` by using `RxDataSource` but it's one way binding.

I want to achieve what I have shown in the picture i.e. I want to bind the `UITextField` from `UITableViewCell` to the `Observable` which is present at some index in the array in `ListViewModel`

I want to do `2 way binding` with the `UITextField` and `answer` property of the `PaletteViewModel`. If the user changes the text in the textField it should change the value in the answer property present at particular index and vice versa.

How Can I achieve something complex like this using `MVVM pattern` using [`ReactiveX`](http://reactivex.io/) frameworks?

What if the `UITableViewCell` at some `IndexPath` is removed from the memory as it's not visible and the observable's value is changed will it result in crash as the `UITextField` at that `IndexPath` will return nil?

Comment: What is the type of `answer`?

Comment: I want to do 2 way binding for UITextField present in the cell with the observable present in a array.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I can probably give you a solution if you tell me the type of the `answer` property.

Comment: Yes it's BehaviorRelay<String?>

Answer (score 3):

A `UITextField` is an *input* element. You don't need a two way binding to it because you shouldn't be dynamically changing it. The most you should do is initialize it and you don't need a binding for that.

You don't mention what the final output will be for this input so the answer may be different than the below. This particular solution assumes that you need to push all the answers as a group to a server or database. Maybe when a button is tapped.

There is a lot of code below, but it compiles as it stands (with the proper imports.) You can subscribe to `ListViewModel.answers` to see all the answers collected together.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    let bag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let answersSubject = PublishSubject<(PaletteID, String)>()
        let viewModel = ListViewModel(answersIn: answersSubject.asObservable())

        viewModel.paletteViewModels
            .bind(to: myTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: MyCell.self)) { index, element, cell in
                cell.answerTextField.text = element.initialAnswer
                cell.answerTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
                    .map { (element.id, $0) }
                    .bind(to: answersSubject)
                    .disposed(by: cell.bag)
            }
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var answerTextField: UITextField!
    let bag = DisposeBag()
}

struct ListViewModel {
    let paletteViewModels: Observable<[PaletteViewModel]>
    let answers: Observable<[PaletteID: String]>

    init(answersIn: Observable<(PaletteID, String)>) {
        paletteViewModels = Observable.just([])
        answers = answersIn
            .scan(into: [PaletteID: String]()) { current, new in
                current[new.0] = new.1
            }
    }
}

struct PaletteViewModel {
    let id: PaletteID
    let initialAnswer: String
}

struct PaletteID: RawRepresentable, Hashable {
    let rawValue: String
}
```

Comment: Wow this is so simple. Thanks for helping.

Comment: So just think if I did 2 way binding and cell containing textfielf is removed from memory and if the observable value is changed then will it result in crash?

Comment: Two way binding doesn't really make any sense. Think about the path the data would take with "two way binding". User enters data in text field which goes to BehaviorRelay which then goes back to the text field... What's the point of that?

Comment: You want to send data to labels. TextFields send data to you.

Comment: Yes you make sense

Comment: @DanielT. the issue is once a text field is changed and then a cell is dequeued we need to set the new value into it. So that may sound like 'two-way- binding...